# How to call a method on an object, when creating it in python?

Tags: python, class, object, methods

I have a question but I don't know exactly how to explain it, so let me put some code here:

```
class 2DVector:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def multiply(self, scalar):
        self.x *= scalar
        self.y *= scalar
```

is it posible to do something like this

```
vector1 = 2DVector(1, 1).multiply(3)
# x == 3, y == 3
```

or do I always have to do it like this

```
vector2 = 2DVector(1, 1)
# x == 1, y == 1
vector2.multiply(3)
# x == 3, y == 3
```

Comment: Have you tried it? Did it work?

Comment: What's the point ? when you do `vector1 = 2DVector(1, 1).multiply(3)`, `vector1` will be `None` and and you'll lose `x` and `y`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `return self` at the end of the `multiply` method allows you to use the first option:

```
class TwoDVector:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def multiply(self, scalar):
        self.x *= scalar
        self.y *= scalar
        return self


if __name__ == '__main__':
    vector = TwoDVector(2, 3).multiply(2)
    # vector.x == 4, vector.y == 6
```

Answer (score 2):

They are equivalent in that they both scale the vector.

But your first example is not very useful it doesn't keep a reference to the class instance. Instead it keeps a reference to the return value of `multiply` (which is just `None`) so your vector reference is lost.

As mentioned you could modify `multiply` to return `self`.

You could also add a scale factor to the constructor:

```
class 2DVector:
    def __init__(self, x, y, scale=1):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.multiply(scale)

# scales vector to (3, 3)
vector1 = 2DVector(1, 1, 3)
```

Comment: ... but OP might want to modify the code for `multiply()` to return `self`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use vector2.multiply(3) directly, you need to adapt your method and return something.

```
    def multiply(self, scalar):
        self.x *= scalar
        self.y *= scalar
        return self
```

But I do not like this solution and prefer :

```
    def multiply(self, scalar):
        return 2DVector(self.x * scalar, self.y * scalar)
```

and treat vector as immutables objects.

Or keeping your first implementation and do

```
vector2 = 2DVector(1, 1)
# x == 1, y == 1
vector2.multiply(3)
# x == 3, y == 3
```